# Flutter BLocConsumer, problem with display data from states when it changes

Tags: flutter, bloc

Bloc version 8.0.1

In builder i display ListView.builder when data loaded, but i also need listener that show alert dialog, and to show it i change state, but after i change state when user click on button, blocbuilder see that state changed and change ListView.builder to other widget that says "error happend"

What can i do with it? Also i am new in bloc,  may u give me detail answer about this problem.

this is my BlocConsumer

```
BlocConsumer<AddCheckListBloc, AddCheckListState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is CheckListTemplateEmpty) {
          return const Text("");
        } else if (state is CheckListTemplateLoading) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else if (state is CheckListTemplateLoaded) {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: state.loadedTemplates.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                if (state.loadedTemplates[index].isPaid == "True") {
                  return InkWell(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 141, 166, 255), width: 1), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), color: Colors.grey),
                      width: 50,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 14),
                      height: 80,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            state.loadedTemplates[index].name,
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                          ),
                          Text(state.loadedTemplates[index].price.toString())
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      addCheckListBloc.add(ShowAlertDialogEvent(state.loadedTemplates[index]));
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 141, 166, 255), width: 1), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), color: Colors.white),
                      width: 50,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 14),
                      height: 80,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            state.loadedTemplates[index].name,
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              });
        } else {
          return const Center(
            child: Text("Ошибка, информацию недоступна к загрузке с сервера"),
          );
        }
      },
      listener: (context, state) {
        {
          if (state is OpenAlertDialogState) {
            SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    String description = "";
                    return AlertDialog(
                      title: const Text("Добавить чеклист?"),
                      content: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 141, 166, 255), width: 1), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), color: Colors.white),
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: const InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: "Описание", border: InputBorder.none),
                          maxLines: null,
                          onChanged: (String value) async {
                            description = value;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      actions: [
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            // Сделать что-то, чтобы закрыть диалог вместе с блоком
                          },
                          child: const Text("Нет"),
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            addCheckListBloc.add(AddNewCheckList(state.checkListTemplate, description));
                          },
                          child: const Text("Да"),
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  });
            });
          }
          if (state is CloseAlertDialogState) {
            SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            });
          }
          ;
        }
      },
    );
```

this is my Bloc

```
class AddCheckListBloc extends Bloc<AddCheckListEvent, AddCheckListState> {
  final CheckListRepository _checkListRepository;
  AddCheckListBloc({required CheckListRepository checkListRepository})
      : _checkListRepository = checkListRepository,
        super(CheckListTemplateLoading()) {
    on<OnCheckListTemplateLoad>((event, Emitter<AddCheckListState> emit) => _loadCheckListTemplates(event, emit));
    on<AddNewCheckList>((event, emit) => _addNewCheckList(event, emit));
    on<ShowAlertDialogEvent>((event, emit) => _showAlertDialog(event, emit));
  }

  Future<void> _loadCheckListTemplates(OnCheckListTemplateLoad event, Emitter emit) async {
    emit(CheckListTemplateLoading());
    try {
      final List<CheckListTemplate> loadedTemplates = await _checkListRepository.getCheckListTemplateList();
      emit(CheckListTemplateLoaded(loadedTemplates: loadedTemplates));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      emit(CheckListTemplateError());
    }
  }

  Future<void> _addNewCheckList(AddNewCheckList event, Emitter<AddCheckListState> emit) async {
    emit(AddingNewCheckList());
    try {
      final template = event.checkListTemplate;
      List<CheckListPoint> _checkListPointList = [];
      for (int i = 0; i < template.checkListPointList!.length; i++) {
        CheckListPoint _checkListPoint = CheckListPoint(false, false, template.checkListPointList![i].requirement, template.checkListPointList![i].notes, false, template.checkListPointList![i].requirementDetails);
        _checkListPointList.add(_checkListPoint);
      }
      CheckList _checkList = CheckList(template.name, event.description, template.advice, _checkListPointList, 0, template.checkListPointList!.length, 0, 0);
      _checkListRepository.saveCheckList(_checkList);
      emit(NewCheckListAdded());
    } catch (e) {
      emit(AddNewCheckListError());
    }
  }

  Future<void> _showAlertDialog(ShowAlertDialogEvent event, Emitter emit) async {
    emit(OpenAlertDialogState(event.checkListTemplate));
  }
}
```